# angularJS model with table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I have a part of my code like this :

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>userId</th>
            <th>title</th>
        </tr>                   
    </thead>
    <tbody>         
        <tr ng-repeat="post in posts">
        <td>user id : {{ post.userId }}</td>
        <td>post title :{{ post.title }}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

but once i remove the ng-repeat directive from **tr** element and add it to a wrapping **div** it doesn't work !!

After adding a parent div, the tbody content is :

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <tr>
        <td>user id : {{ post.userId }}</td>
        <td>post title :{{ post.title }}</td>
    </tr>                       
</div>
```

can anyone tells me why this is happening (i'm using angularjs1.4)

Comment: This is wrong html. <tr> can only be child of <table>

Comment: Any reason why you want divs inside the table? If you want to define section, just use do the ng-repeat in the tbody.

Comment: yes i know that it is wrong, but i'm trying to understand why this is not working is it something related to angularJS philosophy or something like that ?

Answer (score -1):

> ..but once i remove the ng-repeat directive from tr element and add it
>   to a wrapping div it doesn't work !!

Well, thats because the wrapping `<div>` is inside `<tbody>` which is not valid.

(un)fortunately, `<table>` tags in HTML are very picky about their child node types(and overall structure), which is why it can't support `<div>` tag(and others) inside `<tbody>`

Comment: Why a downvote ? Which part of answer is wrong/not acceptable ?